# Convert Radian to Degrees Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to write a function that calculates Radian (Decimals) to Degrees.

For example

`radiansToDegrees(1.5) = 1° 30' 00"`

This is my logic:

1. Using `fix()`, take the whole number before the decimal. This will be the degree.
2. Take the remaining fraction (`0.5` in the above case) and multiply by `60`. From the answer, take the whole number before the comma. This becomes the minutes.
3. Take the remaining fraction from step 2. (`0` in the above case) and multiply by `60`. This becomes the seconds.

I'm only able to reach step one. How do I retain only the fraction part of a number, especially if its something like this `0.8987724`

Comment: `rem ( value, 1 )` will give you the fraction part

Comment: Just subtract (if the number is positive) the whole part, which you already computed with `fix`

Comment: Is your input a string?

Comment: Also there is no 'comma' in your input, is your input structured differently or what's going on?

Comment: @krisdestruction, my bad. In german, the decimal point is just refered to as `komma`. I translated it directly to english. My input is a double.

Comment: what's wrong with using `rad2deg`?

Answer (score 1):

You may use functions from the Mapping Toolbox:

```
degrees = rad2deg(1.5)
dms = degrees2dms(degrees)
--------------------------------
dms = [85.0000, 56.0000, 37.2094]
```

Comment: Yes this is a better approach, better than using my answer :) +1

Comment: I remember there was a function, but I forgot it was called `degrees2dms`

Comment: Thought so, might be worth adding that info to the answer